# How can I register multiple hotkeys?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a WPF app, and searched how to register multiple hotkeys for hours. Ex) 1. Pressing CTRL+F1->mouse right click
2. Pressing CTRL+F2->mouse left click
However, I got no clear solutions for it.

I tried:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hwnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

private HwndSource _source;
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
      base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
      var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
      _source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(helper.Handle);
      _source.AddHook(HwndHook);
      RegisterHotKey(helper.Handle, HOTKEY_ID, MOD_CTRL, VK_F10);
}
private IntPtr HwndHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
      const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
      switch (msg)
      {
            case WM_HOTKEY:
                    switch (wParam.ToInt32())
                    {
                        case HOTKEY_ID:
                            //Something to do
                            handled = true;
                            break;
                    }
            break;
      }
      return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Comment: Please follow this site's tagging guidelines and avoid putting tags in your question title.

Comment: So you successfully register a hot key and capture it. Then what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for something like this?

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F1" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Add handling for the command in your code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2015/03/31/implementing-global-hot-keys-in-wpf/) blog post for an example of how to implement global hot keys in WPF:

```
private const uint VK_F1 = 0x70;
private const uint VK_F2 = 0x71;

protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

    IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
    source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle);
    source.AddHook(HwndHook);

    const int HOTKEY_ID = 9000;
    const uint MOD_CONTROL = 0x0002;
    RegisterHotKey(handle, HOTKEY_ID, MOD_CONTROL, VK_F1); //CTRL + F1
}

private IntPtr HwndHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_HOTKEY:
            switch (wParam.ToInt32())
            {
                case HOTKEY_ID:
                    int vkey = (((int)lParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
                    if (vkey == VK_F1)
                    {
                        //handle...
                    }
                    handled = true;
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```